# MLP Regressor worst than Kernel Ridge Regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

I'm working on a regression problem. I've got a dataset on which I've done feature engineering (imputing missing values, box cox transformed the skewed variables, etc.).

I train and test several models using cross_val_score with 5 splits of the dataset. First I've tried models like  Kernel Ridge Regression, Lasso, Elastic Net, Gradient Boosting. Then I tried the MLPRegressor from scikit learn.
However, using a Root Mean Squared error, results are much better with "simple" models than MLP Regressor (e.g. the mean score for Kernel Ridge is 0.1153, and for MLPRegressor (hidden_layer_sizes=(256,)*25) is 0.1461 and it's the best that I've found running different architectures).

Code for the examples:

```
KRR = KernelRidge(alpha=0.6, kernel='polynomial', degree=2, coef0=2.5)

mlpreg = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(256,)*25,activation='relu',solver='adam',
                      verbose=0)
```

And the function I use for scoring:

```
def rmsle_crossval(model, train: pd.DataFrame, y_train: List[float]):
    kf = KFold(n_folds, shuffle=True, 
               random_state=42).get_n_splits(train.values)
    rmse= np.sqrt(-cross_val_score(model, train.values, y_train, 
                  scoring="neg_mean_squared_error", cv = kf))
    return(rmse)
```

Even if I try MLPRegressor with a single hidden layer of 1 and the same parameters as KRR to be as close to KRR as possible, I've got a score of 0.4381.

Do you have any idea why there is such a difference ?

Edit :
Shape of data: (1460, 81)

Comment: Without knowing the size of the dataset, its very hard to comment what is happening. Can you please share the dataset size?

Comment: The shape of data is (1460, 81)

Answer (score 1):

If by applying a method expected to show a higher variance of the estimates (such as a neural network) you get results inferior to a method characterized by a higher bias (such as a kernel ridge regression) you may suspect one of these two reasons:

1) your problem is unfit for neural networks and it is much more suitable for other models as stated by the no free lunch theorem (http://no-free-lunch.org/)

2) you are overfitting when training your high variance estimator

given the neural network you are using and the small size of the data (1460, 81), in your case I presume it is the second reason.

In fact, if you check your neural network model:

```
>>> mlpreg
MLPRegressor(activation='relu', alpha=0.0001, batch_size='auto', beta_1=0.9,
       beta_2=0.999, early_stopping=False, epsilon=1e-08,
       hidden_layer_sizes=(256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256
, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256),
       learning_rate='constant', learning_rate_init=0.001, max_iter=200,
       momentum=0.9, nesterovs_momentum=True, power_t=0.5,
       random_state=None, shuffle=True, solver='adam', tol=0.0001,
       validation_fraction=0.1, verbose=0, warm_start=False)
```

It seems that you are using 25 layers of 256 nodes each, which accounts to such a large number of parameters to be estimated that hundreds of thousands of examples would not suffice, not just the few you have available.

I suggest you try a smaller network first such as:

```
mlpreg = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(8,), activation='relu', solver='adam',
                      verbose=0)
```

and then try to build up more complex architectures by extending the first layer or by adding a second one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Luca.
I tried with many smaller networks but I still got huge score with the RMSE. (With just two layers, I managed to get 0.1761 with a layer of (99,31) )
The other thing that really surprises me is the fact that when I try MLPRegressor with a single hidden layer of 1 and the same parameters as KRR (activation='identity') to be as close to KRR as possible, I've got a score of 0.4381. However, MLP Regressor would be similar to Kernel Ridge Regressor wouldn't it ?

Comment: Well, not exactly, a Kernel Ridge Regression is more similar to a SVR than a neural network. As my only further suggestion, I'd propose to give up MLPRegressor, after all it is just a toy function, and build a neural network regressor using Keras (there are a few tutorials online, just replicate one of them).